# JSON.stringify is ignoring my nested objects

Tags: javascript, android, json, titanium, titanium-alloy

I have a simple javascript object with some device information including last known geolocation (longitude and latitude only). I'm using JSON.stringify to turn this object in to JSON, but the one variable I have that isn't boolean/text/number gets ignored.

```
exports.CallContext = function() {
var deviceId;
var applicationId;
var userLocation = {lat:0, lon:0};
var operatingSystem;

this.create = function(b) {     
    this.deviceId = Titanium.Platform.id;
    this.applicationId = Alloy.Globals.appId;
    Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function(e) {
        if(e.error) {
            Ti.API.info(e.error);
        } else {
            this.userLocation = {lat:e.coords.latitude, lon:e.coords.longitude};
        }
    });
    this.operatingSystem = Titanium.Platform.version;
};
};
```

After doing `JSON.stringify(myCallContext);` I get a JSON object with deviceId, applicationId and operatingSystem (etc., some omitted), not sure why it isn't including userLocation. Tried turning it in to an array, didn't work still, and still doesn't include it when I get rid of the getCurrentLocation and leave it with dummy info.

Comment: did you get anything by logging `this.userLocation`?

Answer (score 1):

You have to implement toJSON() function inside nested objects to be able to serialize them to JSON format correctly

More info [here](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/3.0/#!/api/Global.JSON-method-stringify)

Comment: Sorry no not it! One of my first thoughts too. I think my geolocation request was not working at all.

Answer (score 0):

you need to define userLocation  as object 
example :

```
  var userLocation =[];
```

and then set lat & lon as items in object ex->

```
 userLocation [0]=0 ;//as lat
    userLocation [1]=0;//as lon
```

Comment: I already am doing that. I think the problem is to do with the Titanium.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition call as when I get rid of that and replace it with just `this.userLocation = {lon:fake, lat:fake};` it does get serialized.